# If, Then, Duplicate Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, duplicates, formula

Column "A" is a numbering column for each Row, some numbers are the same, ie..

A1 is  1
A2 is  3
A3 is  1
A4 is  3

I need a formula that will show how many cells with content are in this column without counting duplicates, as above would be 2. I was figuring an "If-Then" formula but am unable to get it straight. Any help out there? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2013, I want to say that there's a count distinct function. Nonetheless, you can do it like this:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A4,A1:A4)>0,1))
```

EDIT: Adding an explanation. The `FREQUENCY` function gets the frequency of the unique values within the array `A1:A4` (first parameter), binning it using the values within `A1:A4` (second parameter). The `IF` checks to see if that returns anything, i.e. if the frequency is greater than 0, in which case it returns 1 for each unique value it finds. Then the `SUM` adds the number of 1s returned by the `IF` statement, in turn giving you the number of unique values within the array `A1:A4`.